# virtualbox : port forwarding doesnt work

Tags: virtualbox, centos, port-forwarding

I happened to see how to go about fixing this issue of port forwarding , none of them work. Here are the settings, I am trying to access 8888 from host(Windows) and VM had the following settings.

I also setup forwarding rules from Virtualbox, it didnt work .

```
(base) [root@localhost ~]# iptables -A INPUT -p tcp -m state --state NEW -m tcp --dport 8888 -j ACCEPT
(base) [root@localhost ~]# netstat -na | grep 8888
tcp        0      0 127.0.0.1:8888          0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN
tcp6       0      0 ::1:8888                :::*                    LISTEN
```

[image]

Comment: I started juypter on the guest vm and it seems it is listening at 127.0.0.1.  Is it because  of it  ? should i change it to listen for all interfaces  ?

Answer (score 1):

All good now . It is NOT the problem with port forwarding but juypter . Initially (without --ip 0.0.0.0) started listeing @127.0.0.1 which can by accessed only by guest VM and cant be reached by host. With --ip 0.0.0.0, it accepts the traffic from host too.
I started the juypter to listen for all interfaces

jupyter notebook --ip 0.0.0.0